# Configuring softvol in ALSA

Tags: linux, pcm, alsa, debian-based

I have a problem with a USB Sound Card: I cannot change the volume with alsamixer. I created a file called .asoundrc in order to create softvolume control. I made a mess because the default device is just for playback, and now have 3 controls: Master, PCM and Capture, and should have one. I would like to revert that first, I already deleted the file, but those controls still there even if I reboot. Then I would like to add a softvol to the USB Sound Card. Here is a list of my lsusb:

```
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0424:9512 Standard Microsystems Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0424:ec00 Standard Microsystems Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 1130:f211 Tenx Technology, Inc. TP6911 Audio Headset
```

And this my list of devices listed by aplay -l command:

```
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: ALSA [bcm2835 ALSA], device 0: bcm2835 ALSA [bcm2835 ALSA]
  Subdevices: 8/8
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
  Subdevice #1: subdevice #1
  Subdevice #2: subdevice #2
  Subdevice #3: subdevice #3
  Subdevice #4: subdevice #4
  Subdevice #5: subdevice #5
  Subdevice #6: subdevice #6
  Subdevice #7: subdevice #7
card 1: AUDIO [USB  AUDIO], device 0: USB Audio [USB Audio]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

I found that I need to set something like this in my .asoundrc, but i'm not sure how is it in my case:

```
pcm.newdevice {
    type            softvol
    slave.pcm       "default"
    control.name    "Softmaster"
    control.card    0
}
```

I'm using Debian

UPDATE:
I have the following Configuration:
pcm.softvol {
        type softvol
        slave {
           pcm "hw:1,0"
        }
        control {
           name "Volume out"
           card 1
        }
}

pcm.!default {
    type             plug
    slave.pcm       "softvol"
    slave.channels  2
}

But now, I have two controls with the same name, even when each one are marked as Playback and Capture, I changes one and the another control changes too! How do I know that is not the same control? How can I have a control for the "Mic In" of the same device? I've tried copying the same as pcm.softvol section, but changing name to "Volume IN" and pcm "hw:1,1" and didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

The additional controls are saved in `/var/lib/alsa/asound.state` (or `/etc/asound.state` in other distributions).
Unload the sound driver modules and then remove the entries from that file.

If you want to show the control up for the USB device, use `card 1`.

For the softvol control to have any effect, you must tell your application(s) to use device name `newdevice`.

Comment: ¿Can I remove the entire file safely?

Comment: You will lose the values of all mixer controls.

Comment: which values? Volume values? They will be reset to default?

Comment: Yes. (You could just delete the entries for the controls you don't want.)

Comment: I delete the entire file, and reboot. They are back again! :S

Comment: The controls are stored in memory, and saved when you shut down. This is why I told you to unload the modules (try `modprobe -r snd-usb-audio snd-hda-intel`).